# owl-carousel and fullpage js

Tags: owl-carousel, fullpage.js

I'm using owl-carousel and fullpage.js in one time. I give bacground-image to `.section` in `fullpage.js`. How I can change the `.section` 's background when owl next or prew button clicked with animation

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you provide some example code to show what you've tried and where your issue is? Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so we can better help you.

Comment: It would be easier to answer you if you provide an isolated reproduction in codepen or jsfiddle. Otherwise seems quite impossible as the question is very abstract.